# specify a env variable on gradle properties?

Tags: android, gradle, environment-variables, android-gradle-plugin

Hi is it possible to specify a env variable name instead of a full path inside the gradle.properties file?

I have a path set like this:

```
guardit4jpath=/Users/me/Public/GuardIT_for_Java_5.1
```

Is there a way to specifiy this like below instead:

```
guardit4jpath=GuardIt_HOME
```

as an example?

I cant seem to find any info on how this can be done if ever?

Kind regards

Comment: I have the same question... It doesn't work out of the box. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you got any solution?